# JS formdata Chrome on iOS

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to upload images to my server from a WebApp. I'm using Formdata to prepare my data:

```
var dataView = new DataView(savedImage.value.data);
var blob = new Blob([dataView], { type: savedImage.value.type });

var file = new File([blob], savedImage.value.filename);

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('filename', obj.filename);
fd.append('data', file);
fd.append('guid', obj.guid);
fd.append('filepath', obj.filepath);
```

And then I use Jquery to send it:

```
return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: url,
    async:true,
})
```

This however does not work on Chrome for iOS(10.3) I don't even get any errors. Can anyone verify this behavior and an alternative way to accomplish this?

*This works on Chrome for Desktop*

**EDIT 1**
It seems that it is the creating of a file from a blob that is not supported in Chrome for iOS. Anyone have any experience with this?

Also can anyone tell me why on CanIUse and other sites, there are no specific Chrome for iOS category?

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late, but just for anyone else who has the same issue.
I had the same problem and fixed by formData.append Blob instead of a File.

Comment: I was able to use FormData with Safari on iOS 10.3.3 (iPhone 5C period) as well.